# Add an empty line after a specific line in the file

Tags: python, bash, sed

Can someone help me please? I want to add empty line (enter) after line with  "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and empty line (enter) before line with "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

All data in the file not static so I think it can be done using sed or python based on the number of line (the number of lines is always the same)...

Here is my file (opened using vi with "set nu" command):

```
      1 oc_ci:
  2   password: kyvmRHb88c7Y6JJnkqsdkYj4R
  3   username: admin
  4 uc_ci:
  5   password: 7a43ba66480b633195acd7a33f627545e9e87f1c
  6   tenant: admin
  7   username: admin
  8 uc_ssh_creds:
  9   username: heat-admin
 10   password: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 11 MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAr0Kj5sL7QrkMn5+YK7/0DxCeeYmV0qTBbOTv0SGf4FHUKiNO
 12 ZcHnQHY+AF/ilAliyL9nxFW04nsVPwLWFQRunDu2SS9d05cRYwZJqLyrwNMAAMeg
 13 GeDGlVk2MDChNoRrDZZJ1PfRBME9SF1jHfPDnms18CEEGWUff1Tjad6toM/draKP
 14 Keh6M0Rs1slVUjACyB1H3I9GceY7k8aQUJtHKR/6u/X3ae4k27+yEFGx4ail1XvR
 15 zq9kaqQbiCxe2P+NMFVIZQsCXgl9v9pux1WLyg3xYnLCtdgJfttQNkpmvApAhSXg
 16 Yjyr19po8hYUSGWbOk1xjPSFNmAJodFaL9LN4QIDAQABAoIBAAIp124c0A81y5MY
 17 3D8GApRBB0PG0AOmpwCaHt+9A4U4XV8bynb1Gs6v5voINPrQ1thVjIle6Xm2PT/m
 18 4A+oW1kwX4KtxAG9pqhLRpN/qLsbn69ix3YqUSk8za9wmjzbC5tCVKz9ViYx4HjJ
 19 NlUDUlHdTvAk6DEMD4R53sjKx+fpQ76Qrxr7WHGJAtr1LQz2xr1hnxpdc5h4gaXy
 20 Bs1Qui0M3+q1w6DsdNXLR9ZM01QN+6vOHhdJFqHYxUq/C3s+wjouQIYJN7z8/ZVu
 21 QWo4n5ZOxDFjiCxUuo47Wzqwtuyu+gdheHz6vNsMBGEAZRlUvG0TP7buSf6/UFF6
 22 7WTjJWUCgYEA2/kcA1SDg5GMK2ZPjd+u9XL2JPg1RX7w7ooLkSW2r90opk2F5G9Q
 23 42DUvvA9oF0JYBfG5+SyzBnVEVeKcNXFquPewEe/IKrkHe5ed2Ju9OnntjmoCQkN
 24 MUVEWVqiaIIocSZdeVvWgsjMoujthTqkFanU4Pk0M1KsD8FBAWwPCY8CgYEAy/bX
 25 qLxAwTDsWDuezMhQaf/qiwFJ4LJfRUzrLPFzJmXl755SOLvuqD5w66nWKev/35kR
 26 B9komy8jfELhJUw/bi8y6DiXlQ5d1giYfq38e///d4zfv7sQLk8ir1Pr1UeFLyNz
 27 UlBf4j6PYRXjOgSho16Th1fxZDtCWnTlgkbqmY8CgYEArefPgcJ7BrU2v8ju9Bb3
 28 Vw1AFBI2625kQ/HXGzVZrMeHr5JyXBq1NE4FY77CudlT5ChoFET2Je32SPOQe4xF
 29 7cig/hq6u7TfC9q7zF6BohaaHbKPajVBvMYqNwo0g7MDDhFqrNsyR8tAHTtRLJcj
 30 ygyuQ/5AiqK9bOc34Uvwx3kCgYEAvV8B/HhM5xI1XfZ9CkUx5Djn2wfnP+hc7Eru
 31 T1wePZh+VGv6ixJyE2NmFGgrn+CuQTwsw8ysFuk9WTH/OFIC0pqf+VwR4SLlnMN+
 32 Up/XvImC98ykMa/M5jIzUfXpEKzGy21utQ5K+BR9qvZXcpa6PKSi9RaB2T3r7XB7
 33 ZunRB6ECgYEAmQ38xl7AZgIW0rkEe/9mm0naMwG4YPXVYJxByRfmaoJ7qK9dEDYa
 34 tUNg+crSvl+JZxprkARZTjIq4Mwbg/JL/q5etM6tK4BKuJGSCGEqZ16fUYFUyDj1
 35 c2q99tcpGItrbccHjRjSbxk2FVDTnhbxmftWFYelTM/uIJTcgEtNpzU=
 36 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

What I want (manually were added two empty lines):

```
      1 oc_ci:
  2   password: kyvmRHb88c7Y6JJnkqsdkYj4R
  3   username: admin
  4 uc_ci:
  5   password: 7a43ba66480b633195acd7a33f627545e9e87f1c
  6   tenant: admin
  7   username: admin
  8 uc_ssh_creds:
  9   username: heat-admin
 10   password: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 11 
 12 MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAr0Kj5sL7QrkMn5+YK7/0DxCeeYmV0qTBbOTv0SGf4FHUKiNO
 13 ZcHnQHY+AF/ilAliyL9nxFW04nsVPwLWFQRunDu2SS9d05cRYwZJqLyrwNMAAMeg
 14 GeDGlVk2MDChNoRrDZZJ1PfRBME9SF1jHfPDnms18CEEGWUff1Tjad6toM/draKP
 15 Keh6M0Rs1slVUjACyB1H3I9GceY7k8aQUJtHKR/6u/X3ae4k27+yEFGx4ail1XvR
 16 zq9kaqQbiCxe2P+NMFVIZQsCXgl9v9pux1WLyg3xYnLCtdgJfttQNkpmvApAhSXg
 17 Yjyr19po8hYUSGWbOk1xjPSFNmAJodFaL9LN4QIDAQABAoIBAAIp124c0A81y5MY
 18 3D8GApRBB0PG0AOmpwCaHt+9A4U4XV8bynb1Gs6v5voINPrQ1thVjIle6Xm2PT/m
 19 4A+oW1kwX4KtxAG9pqhLRpN/qLsbn69ix3YqUSk8za9wmjzbC5tCVKz9ViYx4HjJ
 20 NlUDUlHdTvAk6DEMD4R53sjKx+fpQ76Qrxr7WHGJAtr1LQz2xr1hnxpdc5h4gaXy
 21 Bs1Qui0M3+q1w6DsdNXLR9ZM01QN+6vOHhdJFqHYxUq/C3s+wjouQIYJN7z8/ZVu
 22 QWo4n5ZOxDFjiCxUuo47Wzqwtuyu+gdheHz6vNsMBGEAZRlUvG0TP7buSf6/UFF6
 23 7WTjJWUCgYEA2/kcA1SDg5GMK2ZPjd+u9XL2JPg1RX7w7ooLkSW2r90opk2F5G9Q
 24 42DUvvA9oF0JYBfG5+SyzBnVEVeKcNXFquPewEe/IKrkHe5ed2Ju9OnntjmoCQkN
 25 MUVEWVqiaIIocSZdeVvWgsjMoujthTqkFanU4Pk0M1KsD8FBAWwPCY8CgYEAy/bX
 26 qLxAwTDsWDuezMhQaf/qiwFJ4LJfRUzrLPFzJmXl755SOLvuqD5w66nWKev/35kR
 27 B9komy8jfELhJUw/bi8y6DiXlQ5d1giYfq38e///d4zfv7sQLk8ir1Pr1UeFLyNz
 28 UlBf4j6PYRXjOgSho16Th1fxZDtCWnTlgkbqmY8CgYEArefPgcJ7BrU2v8ju9Bb3
 29 Vw1AFBI2625kQ/HXGzVZrMeHr5JyXBq1NE4FY77CudlT5ChoFET2Je32SPOQe4xF
 30 7cig/hq6u7TfC9q7zF6BohaaHbKPajVBvMYqNwo0g7MDDhFqrNsyR8tAHTtRLJcj
 31 ygyuQ/5AiqK9bOc34Uvwx3kCgYEAvV8B/HhM5xI1XfZ9CkUx5Djn2wfnP+hc7Eru
 32 T1wePZh+VGv6ixJyE2NmFGgrn+CuQTwsw8ysFuk9WTH/OFIC0pqf+VwR4SLlnMN+
 33 Up/XvImC98ykMa/M5jIzUfXpEKzGy21utQ5K+BR9qvZXcpa6PKSi9RaB2T3r7XB7
 34 ZunRB6ECgYEAmQ38xl7AZgIW0rkEe/9mm0naMwG4YPXVYJxByRfmaoJ7qK9dEDYa
 35 tUNg+crSvl+JZxprkARZTjIq4Mwbg/JL/q5etM6tK4BKuJGSCGEqZ16fUYFUyDj1
 36 c2q99tcpGItrbccHjRjSbxk2FVDTnhbxmftWFYelTM/uIJTcgEtNpzU=
 37 
 38 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help you here.

```
awk '/BEGIN RSA/{$0=$0 ORS} /END RSA/{$0=ORS $0}1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above command too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Tons of ways, e.g. using awk:

```
awk '/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/ { print "" }
{ print }
/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/ { print "" }' origfile.txt >result.txt
```

Vi too can probably be scripted to open file, add two lines and close (at least Vim can.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

'\n' in python adds a new line use where you want to add a new line in the string

Comment: Yes I know about \n. But it was preferable not to use python. Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `sed`.

```
sed "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/" origfile > newfile
```

Comment: The hold space must be empty. `seq 1 7 | sed '/6/ G;'` inserts an empty line afte 6, but `seq 1 7 | sed '/4/ h; /6/ G;'` will add a number. Perhaps `sed "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/" origfile > newfile` is safer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  And for a such detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/BEGIN RSA/G;/END RSA/i\\' file
```

Append the empty hold space after the line containing `BEGIN RSA` and insert an empty line before the line containing `END RSA`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!